# How to pick column from one table and update in second when first table is returning more than 1 records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
UPDATE FirstDates
SET FirstDates.Date = (SELECT TOP 1 FirstDates.Date 
                       FROM FirstDates 
                       INNER JOIN SecondDates ON FirstDates.Location = SecondDates.Location)     
FROM FirstDates
INNER JOIN SecondDates ON FirstDates.Location = SecondDates.Location
```

Actually I want the `top 1 FirstDates` to be updated in `Date` column of `SecondDates` where both `Dates` matches but the problem is that `FirstDates` returns more than 1 records for each matching `date` and among every matching record I want to pick the `top 1 Date from FirstDates` and update in `SecondDates` table.

See

```
SELECT Dates FROM FirstDates WHERE Location = 'ISR'
```

returns

```
ID   Date
----------------
 1  2017-01-09
 2  2017-08-12
```

Now that Last date i.e. 2 needs to be updated in the `SecondTable` but when the Location of `SecondDate` table matches the Location of `FirstTable`, then only and should only pick the last date i.e. at 2 from `FirstDates`.

Now whenever the `location` matches it will return more than 1 records from `FirstTable` and we need to pick the last one and put that in `SecondTable`'s `date` column, that's it.

Comment: In your code you are updating FirstDates.Date but then you say: *I want to pick the top 1 Date from FirstDates and update in SecondDates table*. Your question is not clear about the the target. So clarify and better post sample data and expected results.

Comment: Never use `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`, and please post some sample data and expected results as formatted text not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `group by Location` the table `FirstDates` to get the last `Date` for each `Location` and then join to `SecondDates` to perform the update:

```
update s
set s.Date = f.Date
from SecondDates s inner join (
  select Location, max(Date) Date
  from FirstDates
  group by Location
) f on f.Location = s.Location
```

Comment: thanks a lot but what if more columns in SecondTable needs to be updated from FirstTable? E.g. Set s.Name= f.Name, s.CellNo= f.CellNo.

Comment: I know that we can select more columns in select statement i.e. f but grouping them would present unwanted results.

Comment: If the requirement is different than what you ask in your question then post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I am little bit confused here,Which table should updated FirstDate or SecondDates?

```
UPDATE FirstDates 
SET FirstDates.Date = (SELECT MAX(SecondDates.Date) 
                       FROM SecondDates 
                       WHERE FirstDates.Location= SecondDates.Location)
```

Comment: the problem is that FirstDates returns more than 1 records for each matching date and among every matching record I want to pick the top 1 Date from FirstDates and update in SecondDates table.

Comment: SecondDates needs to be updated using the Date from FIrstDates but the problem is that matching record from FirstDates return more than 1 records and I want to pick the Top 1 date from FirstDates in each match sets of records.